# NodeJS 'Require' loading library in coffeescript, empty object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, coffeescript

I've come across an interesting problem in NodeJS that pops up now and then at work, and I haven't been able to figure it out.

I've written a back-end in CoffeeScript, which I then compile with grunt-contrib-coffee into Javascript in a ~/bin directory. I also include a library that I privately host on Bitbucket with the appropriate private keys, and install through npm. This library too is written in coffeescript.

Usually I'm able to include this library in Javascript without any headaches, using a simple require just like I would for any other library. However, occasionally one of the servers that's using the back-end gets updates, and it stops working. When I go check the error, it's always the same - 'require' passes, but instead of loading the actual library in JavaScript, it returns an empty object ({}). Running the code in coffeescript still works, but regardless of what I do - recompile, reinstall all dependencies, remove and clone the repository, the problem persists.

I've run out of ideas of what it might be myself, so I'm hoping that someone here has come across the problem before and might be able to point me in the right direction.

In the library package.json:

```
{ 
    "name": "graph-engine",
    "main": "./lib/graph"
}
```

In the library's graph.coffee

```
class Graph
    constructor: () ->
      # Perform init

module.exports = Graph
```

Then in the app's package.json:

```
{
    "graph-engine": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:<team>/graph-engine.git"
}
```

Finally, in the app itself:

```
GraphEngine = require "graph-engine"
engineInstance = new GraphEngine()
```

This works fine in coffeescript, but when compiling the app using grunt with the following setup for grunt-contrib-coffee:

```
coffee:
  glob_to_multiple: 
    expand: true
    flatten: false
    cwd: 'src'
    src: ['**/*.coffee']
    dest: 'bin'
    ext: '.js'
```

It fails to load the library correctly when running the compiled application, instead returning an empty object. Again, I'd like to emphasise that this does not always happen, and as such I didn't include any code or json files as I believed that it was unrelated.

Comment: Where's the code? we have zilch to go on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the exact reason for the randomness of the behaviour eludes me to this day, I have found that it is related to these libraries being written in CoffeeScript.

It seems that depending on the load order, occasionally third party libraries would register coffee script and my own libraries would load correctly, whereas other times these libraries would load after my own libraries had loaded, resulting in an inability to load coffeescript. Therefore, the solution turned out to be fairly straightforward - register coffeescript. This can be done by putting the following at the start of the node.js app:

```
require('coffee-script/register')
```

Refer to the [documentation](http://jashkenas.github.io/coffee-script/#changelog) for further information.