# CoffeeScript Cakefile not finding NPM Module node-glob

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, coffeescript

I am trying to use a code snippet from a [README for node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/blob/master/README.md#usage) in CoffeeScript. I installed the package:

```sh
npm install --global glob
```

I am trying to use the following snippet:

```js
var glob = require("glob")

// options is optional
glob("**/*.js", options, function (er, files) {
   // files is an array of filenames.
   // If the `nonull` option is set, and nothing
   // was found, then files is ["**/*.js"]
   // er is an error object or null.
})
```

and I assume its then written something similar to this in CoffeeScript:

```coffee
# Cakefile
{glob} = require 'glob' # npm install --global glob

task 'glob-test', 'Testing Globs', ->
   glob.sync("**/*.ts") (er, files) ->
      console.log files
```

However, I get the following error messages:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'glob'
```

Am I doing this correctly, or is it even possible CoffeeScript and I should just abandon the whole idea?

UPDATE:

Installed the `node-glob` module as a locally vendored module this time using:

```sh
npm install glob
```

and changed `{glob}` to `glob` in the require statement.

and ran the Cakefile task again. [Got this error this time](https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/fe611188a67478da9777e3c94992de72).

Comment: Have you tried installing the module locally (`npm install glob`, no `--global`)?

Comment: Got a different error this time. `return glob.syn("**/*.ts")(function(err, files) {` the arrow is pointing towards the `ts")(fu` and then `TypeError: glob.sync(...) is not a function`.

Comment: Try changing the require line to `glob = require 'glob'`. I don't think you need those braces around glob.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/predatorian3/fe611188a67478da9777e3c94992de72

Comment: Maybe this similar question will be useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118455/nodejs-require-loading-library-in-coffeescript-empty-object-in-javascript